# Command Prompt doesn't recognize equality

Tags: batch-file, echo, command-prompt

I guess I don't understand how the Windows Command Prompt evaluates equality. I have a batch that looks like this:

```
@echo off
set test=12
if (%test% EQU 12) echo true
pause
```

This, strangely, does not print true. Could anybody tell me why this is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove parentheses and it will work:

```
@echo off
set test=12
if %test% EQU 12 echo true
pause
```

IF doesn't use parentheses in conditions, just run `if /?` and you will get information on it's syntax.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think it would be that simple! A lot of other languages I'm used to have parentheses around the condition.

Comment: @LastStar007: In this case parentheses take part in the comparison, i.e. you were actually comparing (after evaluation) `(12` to `12)`, and the two were naturally different things.